# There is a way to record my game on unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a game that I create and I want to add an option to record the game after I build it.
I find the unity recorder but I can use it only at the editor and I want to create a video that the unity save and then the player can watch it at the future.
someone know a solution for that? it seems that anyone don't try it before(or don't publish about it before).

Comment: Just a minute of googling leads [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/7728186-creating-a-replay-system-in-unity), and I think there are plenty of other materials

Comment: It's not what I'm looking for, on this link I should save the objects position and rotation and then move the objects as the first time.
I'm looking for a real video as a mp4 file

Comment: Okay, I don't see a step-by-step tutorial, but basically you'll need to extract screen texture from unity and feed it to MediaRecorder. [Link](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Media.MediaEncoder.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try using some plug-ins! There are plenty of plug-ins to help you do just that!
As an example, I'm using AVPro to record video in my own project!

Comment: I'm looking for something I can develop myself and not spend 800 dollar

Comment: Maybe you could try ffmpeg, I've recently given up on AVPro and switched to the free ffmpeg for this!